# bootstrap modal not working in IE8 when using a progress tag inside of it

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

i am banging my head with IE8 (going crazy why this browser is even still used).

i am building an app using angular.js and bootstrap which should be supported by IE8 asswell.

my app cureently works perfectly fine with chrom, FF, IE10 and IE9
i have decalred in my index.html at the  tag:

```
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <script src="js/json3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <script>
        document.createElement('login');
        document.createElement('register');
        document.createElement('change-details');
        document.createElement('tooltip-popup-delay');
        document.createElement('tooltip');
        document.createElement('datepicker-popup');


      </script>
    <![endif]-->

<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

and i have a directive (login) which has a templateUrl with the login modal.

i then use it like this:

```
<div ng-show="showNav" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <login></login>
    <register></register>
    .....
.....
```

and this is a part of my login modal (its a login.html which is in the templateUrl directive):

```
   <div modal="shouldBeOpenLogin" close="closeModalLogin()" options="opts">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button ng-disabled="disableButtons" type="button" ng-click="closeModalLogin()" class="close pull-right">&times;</button>
        <h3 style="text-align:center">{{loginHeader}}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="waitLogin" ng-show="showSearching">                   
        <h5> please wait  <progress percent="dynamicObject" class="progress-striped active"></progress><h5>
    </div>

        <form ng-submit="login(loginForm)" name="loginForm" class="form-horizontal">
          <div ng-show="showLoginFields" class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">username</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="email" ng-model="login.username" placeholder="email" title="please enter this field">         
            </div>
          </div>
.....
```

now for some unknow reason it appears that the

i have tried to just put a regullar progress without using the bootstraps one. still not success.

i even tried to put the login.html content inside the index.html instead of using the  directive and still no success.

i have tried to add an document.createElement('progress') and also no success.

please help me before i destroy IE8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `progress` element as well since it is an directive. You missed that.

```
document.createElement('progress');
```